# Return Multi-Term Distinct Values

Tags: elasticsearch

Within an Elastic Search index I am attempting to query by 2 distinct top-level field values from field companyName and field productName, ordered by a generatedDate field and include the domainModelId field.

The following SQL query shows the results of all existing values and I've high-lighted the two unique document rows (in this case) by generatedDate;

```
{
    "query": "SELECT companyName, productName, generatedDate FROM nextware_domain_metaservices_domainmodel ORDER BY generatedDate DESC"
}
```

response as follows:

[image]

I tried the following

```
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": 
  {
    "companies": 
    {
        "terms": 
        {
            "field": "companyName.keyword"
        },
        "aggs": 
        {
            "products": 
            {
                "terms": 
                {
                    "field": "productName.keyword"
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

This returns the correct buckets as follows;

```
 "aggregations": {
    "companies": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "NextWare",
                "doc_count": 18,
                "products": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "ProductPortal",
                            "doc_count": 16
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Domain",
                            "doc_count": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I include the value of domainModelId.Id field without a second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the value of `domainModelId.Id`, you need to use [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "companyName":"NextWare",
    "productName":"Domain",
    "domainModelId.Id":"i"
}
{
    "companyName":"NextWare",
    "productName":"Domain",
    "domainModelId.Id":"c"
}
{
    "companyName":"NextWare",
    "productName":"ProductPortal",
    "domainModelId.Id":"a"
}
{
    "companyName":"NextWare",
    "productName":"ProductPortal",
    "domainModelId.Id":"b"
}
{
    "companyName":"NextWare",
    "productName":"ProductPortal",
    "domainModelId.Id":"d"
}
{
    "companyName":"NextWare",
    "productName":"ProductPortal",
    "domainModelId.Id":"e"
}
{
    "companyName":"NextWare",
    "productName":"ProductPortal",
    "domainModelId.Id":"f"
}
{
    "companyName":"NextWare",
    "productName":"ProductPortal",
    "domainModelId.Id":"g"
}
{
    "companyName":"NextWare",
    "productName":"ProductPortal",
    "domainModelId.Id":"h"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "companies": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "companyName.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "products": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "productName.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_ids": {
              "top_hits": {
                "_source": {
                  "includes": [
                    "domainModelId.Id"
                  ]
                },
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "companies": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "NextWare",
          "doc_count": 9,
          "products": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "ProductPortal",
                "doc_count": 7,
                "top_ids": {
                  "hits": {
                    "total": {
                      "value": 7,
                      "relation": "eq"
                    },
                    "max_score": 1.0,
                    "hits": [
                      {
                        "_index": "67049816",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "1",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "domainModelId.Id": "a"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "_index": "67049816",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "2",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "domainModelId.Id": "b"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "_index": "67049816",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "4",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "domainModelId.Id": "d"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "_index": "67049816",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "5",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "domainModelId.Id": "e"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "_index": "67049816",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "6",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "domainModelId.Id": "f"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "_index": "67049816",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "7",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "domainModelId.Id": "g"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "_index": "67049816",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "8",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "domainModelId.Id": "h"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "key": "Domain",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "top_ids": {
                  "hits": {
                    "total": {
                      "value": 2,
                      "relation": "eq"
                    },
                    "max_score": 1.0,
                    "hits": [
                      {
                        "_index": "67049816",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "3",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "domainModelId.Id": "c"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "_index": "67049816",
                        "_type": "_doc",
                        "_id": "9",
                        "_score": 1.0,
                        "_source": {
                          "domainModelId.Id": "i"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @John Kears please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thank you @ESCoder!   This worked great!  I further included a sort option on the generatedDate field which helped to isolate the specific documents I am looking for.  The underlying data is produced from a code-generator.  The data represents the metadata from the code model as generated. I am developing a model browser which should always and only reflect the metadata from the most recent generated model. The top_hits aggregation is a perfect fit for my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnKears Glad I could help you :-)